# Jenkins pipeline script from a branch and a specific commit does not work

Tags: jenkins

I work with Jenkins and git-gerrit.

I know how to fetch Jenkins pipeline file from a master and take a specific git commit through a jenkins parameter.

I am also able to clone Jenkins pipeline from a specific branch.

I do not know how to combine 1 and 2. 
How can I fetch Jenkins pipeline from a specific branch and specify specific commit?

The picture below shows configuration which is not working.

If I replace branch_1 with a master and I enter a commit sha1 from master branch it works.
If I remove the commitId and leave branch_1 I get the tip of branch_1 in my workspace.
If I I leave branch_1 and commitId from branch_1 like on the picture it does not work.

Error I get is:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]